# Build an Android project with error

Tags: android, android-studio

A unknown error occurs when I was building a android project with Android Studio, and the specific error as follow twisted me.

> ''Error:C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\3.3\scripts\ao5yh51kitdkvn790wbtokixe\init\init2ce2764386e2b8bb7806b691787e7bd8\cache.properties
>   (系统找不到指定的文件(can't find the file specified  )。)''

Comment: Try File->Invalidate caches / Restart in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1.clean project:

click on build>select clean project.

2.build project:

click on build>select build project.

3.invalid caches/Restart studio

click on file>select Invalid caches/Restart.